# How to flip the d3 tree layout from top-bottom to bottom -top and adjust the size to look ok on different devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

i'm using d3 library alongside with react to create family tree layout and i did, but the problem is i want to flip it to make the root lie down and also want make the size look good on different devices just like this tree [Family Tree](https://livefamilytrees.com/trees/?t=210702qAEu) because the tree could become bigger and bigger and contains more than 500 names and also how can i control the text orientation to make it look like the attached image

note:- i'm using ResizeObserver API and i think this what makes the tree looks squashed on mobile devices but when i try to remove it, the problem still exist and i don't know what to do

```js
import {useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import {select,hierarchy, stratify, tree,linkVertical, selectAll} from 'd3'
import { useHistory} from 'react-router'
import useResizeObserver from './useResizeObserver'

const Tree = ({familyData,isProfile}) => {
    const wrapperRef = useRef()
    const dimension = useResizeObserver(wrapperRef)
    const history = useHistory()
    const genColors = [
        '#D92027','#DEEEEA', '#BF1363',
        '#FFF5B7','#94D0CC','#7B6079',
        '#FF8882','#45526C','#FFC93C',
        '#FFB037','#EFF7E1','#839B97',
        '#CEE397','#F5A25D','#625261',
        '#87556F','#E5EDB7','#231E23',
        '#6F0000','#FFF0F5','#FFEBD9',
        '#BEEBE9','#B0A160','#E4F9FF',
    ]
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!dimension) return;
        wrapperRef.current.innerHTML = '';
        const dataStructure = stratify().id(id => id._id).parentId(id => id.parentId)(familyData)
        const root = hierarchy(dataStructure)
        const rootTree = tree().size([dimension.width, dimension.height])
        rootTree(root)
        const linkGenerator = linkVertical().x(node => node.x).y(node => node.y)
        
        const svg = select(wrapperRef.current).append('svg').attr('width','4000').attr('height','650')
        
        svg.selectAll('.node')
            .data(root.descendants())
            .join('circle')
            .attr('r', 5)
            .attr('cx', d => d.x)
            .attr('cy', d => d.y)
            .attr('fill', (d) => {
               return genColors[d.depth]
            })
            .attr('opacity', 0)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.data.depth * 500)
            .attr('opacity', 1)
        
        svg.selectAll('.leaf')
            .data(root.descendants())
            .join('image')
            .attr('href','/image/leaf.png')
            .attr('width', '1.5rem')
            .style('display', (d) => {
                if(!d.children) return 'inline'
                else return 'none'
            })
            .attr('x', d => d.x - 5)
            .attr('y', d => d.y + 15)
            .attr('opacity', 0)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.data.depth * 500)
            .attr('opacity', 1)
        
        svg.selectAll('.link')
            .data(root.links())
            .join('path')
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('d', linkGenerator)
            .attr('stroke', '#555')
            .attr('stroke-width', '2')
            .attr('opacity', '0.5')
            .attr('id',  d => 'link_' + d.target.data.data._id)
            .attr('stroke-dasharray', function(){
                const length = this.getTotalLength()
                return `${length} ${length}`
            })
            .attr('stroke-dashoffset', function(){
                const length = this.getTotalLength()
                return length
            })
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.source.depth * 500)
            .attr('stroke-dashoffset', 0)
            
        svg.selectAll('.name')
            .data(root.descendants())
            .join('text')
            .text(d => d.data.data.firstName)
            .attr('x', d => d.x + 10)
            .attr('y', d => d.y + 15)
            .attr('fill', '#009688')
            .attr('id',  d => 'name_' + d.data.data._id)
            .style('cursor', 'pointer')
            .style('font-size', '1.2rem')
            .style(' z-index', '9999999')
            .on('mouseover', (e, d) => {
                selectAll('path').style('stroke', '#2c3e50')
                selectAll('text').style('fill', '#2c3e50')
                selectAll('circle').style('fill', '#2c3e50')
                selectAll('image').style('opacity', '0.1')
                while(d){
                    if(!d.data.parentId ) {
                        select(`#name_${d.data.data._id}`).style('fill','#f39c12')
                    }
                    if(d.data.parentId !== null){
                        select(`#link_${d.data.data._id}`).style('stroke','#e74c3c');
                        select(`#name_${d.data.data._id}`).style('fill','#f39c12')
                        .style('font-size', '1.2rem')
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .style('font-size', '2.5rem');
                    }
                    d = d.parent
                }
            })
            .on('mouseout', (e, d) => {
                selectAll('path').style('stroke', '#555')
                selectAll('text').style('fill', '#009688').style('font-size', '1.2rem')
                selectAll('image').style('opacity', '1')
                selectAll('circle').style('fill', (d) => {
                    return genColors[d.depth]
                })
            })
            .on('click', (e, d) => {
                if(!isProfile){
                    history.push(`/info/${d.data.data._id}`)
                }
            })
            .attr('opacity', 0)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.data.depth * 500)
            .attr('opacity', 1)
   },[familyData, dimension, history, genColors,isProfile])
    
   return (
    <div ref={wrapperRef} className='tree__wrapper'></div>
   
    )
}

export default Tree
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

and also this is my useResizeObserver Hook

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const useResizeObserver = ref => {
    const [dimension, setDimension] = useState(null)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const targetElement = ref.current
        const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                setDimension(entry.contentRect)
            })
        })
        observer.observe(targetElement)
        return () => {
            observer.unobserve(targetElement)
        }
         
    },[ref])   
    
    return dimension
}

export default useResizeObserver
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you would have to do is invert the y values so that they decrease from the bottom of your SVG instead of increasing from the top. You should do this by using a height variable for consistency. I haven't tested the following code as I don't have the data, but if it doesn't work it should give you the general idea:

````js
import {useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import {select,hierarchy, stratify, tree,linkVertical, selectAll} from 'd3'
import { useHistory} from 'react-router'
import useResizeObserver from './useResizeObserver'

const Tree = ({familyData,isProfile}) => {
    const height = 650 // Based on what you choose, could be a prop
    const width = 4000
    const wrapperRef = useRef()
    const dimension = useResizeObserver(wrapperRef)
    const history = useHistory()
    const genColors = [
        '#D92027','#DEEEEA', '#BF1363',
        '#FFF5B7','#94D0CC','#7B6079',
        '#FF8882','#45526C','#FFC93C',
        '#FFB037','#EFF7E1','#839B97',
        '#CEE397','#F5A25D','#625261',
        '#87556F','#E5EDB7','#231E23',
        '#6F0000','#FFF0F5','#FFEBD9',
        '#BEEBE9','#B0A160','#E4F9FF',
    ]
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!dimension) return;
        wrapperRef.current.innerHTML = '';
        const dataStructure = stratify().id(id => id._id).parentId(id => id.parentId)(familyData)
        const root = hierarchy(dataStructure)
        const rootTree = tree().size([dimension.width, dimension.height])
        rootTree(root)
        const linkGenerator = linkVertical()
                                 .x(node => node.x) // X coord doesn't change
                                 .y(node => height - node.y) // Y coordinate decreases instead of increasing
        
        const svg = select(wrapperRef.current)
                     .append('svg')
                       .attr('width', width) // Use variable for width (optional, but good practice)
                       .attr('height', height) // Use your variable for height
        
        svg.selectAll('.node')
            .data(root.descendants())
            .join('circle')
            .attr('r', 5)
            .attr('cx', d => d.x)
            .attr('cy', d => height - d.y) // subtract the y coord from the height
            .attr('fill', (d) => {
               return genColors[d.depth]
            })
            .attr('opacity', 0)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.data.depth * 500)
            .attr('opacity', 1)
        
        svg.selectAll('.leaf')
            .data(root.descendants())
            .join('image')
            .attr('href','/image/leaf.png')
            .attr('width', '1.5rem')
            .style('display', (d) => {
                if(!d.children) return 'inline'
                else return 'none'
            })
            .attr('x', d => d.x - 5)
            .attr('y', d => (height - d.y) + 15) // Again here subtract
            .attr('opacity', 0)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.data.depth * 500)
            .attr('opacity', 1)
        
        svg.selectAll('.link')
            .data(root.links())
            .join('path')
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('d', linkGenerator)
            .attr('stroke', '#555')
            .attr('stroke-width', '2')
            .attr('opacity', '0.5')
            .attr('id',  d => 'link_' + d.target.data.data._id)
            .attr('stroke-dasharray', function(){
                const length = this.getTotalLength()
                return `${length} ${length}`
            })
            .attr('stroke-dashoffset', function(){
                const length = this.getTotalLength()
                return length
            })
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.source.depth * 500)
            .attr('stroke-dashoffset', 0)
            
        svg.selectAll('.name')
            .data(root.descendants())
            .join('text')
            .text(d => d.data.data.firstName)
            .attr('x', d => d.x + 10)
            .attr('y', d => (height - d.y) + 15) // And again
            .attr('fill', '#009688')
            .attr('id',  d => 'name_' + d.data.data._id)
            .style('cursor', 'pointer')
            .style('font-size', '1.2rem')
            .style(' z-index', '9999999')
            .on('mouseover', (e, d) => {
                selectAll('path').style('stroke', '#2c3e50')
                selectAll('text').style('fill', '#2c3e50')
                selectAll('circle').style('fill', '#2c3e50')
                selectAll('image').style('opacity', '0.1')
                while(d){
                    if(!d.data.parentId ) {
                        select(`#name_${d.data.data._id}`).style('fill','#f39c12')
                    }
                    if(d.data.parentId !== null){
                        select(`#link_${d.data.data._id}`).style('stroke','#e74c3c');
                        select(`#name_${d.data.data._id}`).style('fill','#f39c12')
                        .style('font-size', '1.2rem')
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .style('font-size', '2.5rem');
                    }
                    d = d.parent
                }
            })
            .on('mouseout', (e, d) => {
                selectAll('path').style('stroke', '#555')
                selectAll('text').style('fill', '#009688').style('font-size', '1.2rem')
                selectAll('image').style('opacity', '1')
                selectAll('circle').style('fill', (d) => {
                    return genColors[d.depth]
                })
            })
            .on('click', (e, d) => {
                if(!isProfile){
                    history.push(`/info/${d.data.data._id}`)
                }
            })
            .attr('opacity', 0)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.data.depth * 500)
            .attr('opacity', 1)
   },[familyData, dimension, history, genColors,isProfile])
    
   return (
    <div ref={wrapperRef} className='tree__wrapper'></div>
   
    )
}

export default Tree```
````